# waveform of a closed switch recorded from usb soundcard line input

Tags: audio

This is kind of hard to describe, but I would like to know what kind of waveform pattern would be generated if I close a switch that is plugged into my USB sound card line input.  I am specifically talking about switches used by people with disabilities, such as a very sensitive touch switch or eyeblink switch, which all have a 3.5 mm phono plug to interface with various devices.  I would like my computer to recognize the waveform that would be generated, and then initiate a macro keystroke as a result.  Is this something that can easily be done?

Comment: The switch closure/opening will cause an inconsistent noise.  You should not try to key off such noise.  Instead you should be filtering out the switch noise and switch bounce, and try to detect the simple changes in the voltage levels between the "on" state versus the "off" state.